# Pre-populate (Query) SelectField - WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying pre-populate a Select Field using WTForms.
I want to pre-populate the Select Field (value and label) using data from a database.

Database:

```
+----+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+
| id | category | description                         | status |
+----+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Cinema   | About movies                        |      1 |
|  2 | Play     | About music.                        |      0 |
|  3 | News     | Breaking news                       |      1 |
+----+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+
```

I want a **QuerySelectField** equivalent to this:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    category = SelectField(u'Category', choices=[('1', 'Cinema'), ('3','News')])
```

I've done this so far:

```
def getCategories():
    return Category.query.filter_by(status=1).all()

class MyForm(Form):
    category = QuerySelectField(u'Category',
            [validators.Required()],
            query_factory = getCategories
            )
```

The labels are rendered like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
<option value="1">&lt;models.Category object at 0x105064910&gt;</option>
<option value="3">&lt;models.Category object at 0x105064d50&gt;</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you can try this code

`categorie=QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda:Category.query.filter_by(status=1).all(),get_label="name")`

in your form
you can find more this awesome turorial they use it [simpe crud app with forms](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-crud-web-app-with-python-and-flask-part-two#Forms)

Answer (score 3):

You're doing alright. The QuerySelectField uses the string representation of your Model object for displaying. Just add a `__str__` function to your Category model that returns the category name.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```